# Might Be Old, Might Be Egg

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> The first and oldest, strong and bright
>   Performs his duty dawn to night.
>   Inside a curve a humble stick
>   Does even better - what a trick!
>   Many turnings, night and day,
>   Dust that runs a narrow way.
>   Escapement, weight and turning part
>   Co-operate in ancient art.
>   Resonant geometry
>   Excited electronically.
>   Small and mighty, they're the best
>   When chilled. They govern all the rest.

For the green tick, tell me how I told you the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like these are

> ways to measure time, listed roughly in chronological order of their invention.

**T**he first and oldest, strong and bright / Performs his duty dawn to night.

> Looking at the sun will give the approximate time of day

**I**nside a curve a humble stick /
Does even better - what a trick!

> The sundial gives a more accurate time than just looking at the sun. The simplest sundial is just a curve, where the locations of the shadow of a fixed stick (the gnomon) are marked.

**M**any turnings, night and day, /
Dust that runs a narrow way.

> An hourglass has sand running in it, but you need to keep flipping it over when it runs out.

**E**scapement, weight and turning part /
Co-operate in ancient art.

> A mechanical clock has an [escapement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escapement), a weight (the pendulum), and clock hands that turn

**R**esonant geometry  /
Excited electronically.

> A quartz clock works by running electricity to a quartz crystal, which responds piezoelectrically, and starts to vibrate in a very predictable manner, which gives a very accurate way to measure time.

**S**mall and mighty, they're the best /
When chilled. They govern all the rest.

> Atomic clocks are currently the best way to measure time, the time they keep is considered definitive, and all other clocks are synchronised to them. Chilling an atomic clock (eg. with liquid nitrogen, or even close to the absolute zero with lasers) reduces the background noise and slows the atoms down. Both of the effects improve the accuracy of measurement.

That would make the title into

> old-timer and egg timer (This is probably what the crypto speaking @jafe is suggesting below)

And OP told me the answer

> in a timely manner, one clue at a time, and probably in his spare time.

Kudos to Level 51 for spotting the acrostic.

Comment: This has to be it. The title could refer to rot13(byq-gvzre naq rtt gvzre).

Comment: Looking good but... tell me how I told you. ;-)

Comment: Adding on to this, rot13(gur fgnegvat yrggre bs rirel bgure yvar fcryyf bhg GVZREF) - I'm guessing that's the intended answer, which fits with the title's terminology too

Comment: @Level51 Correct! When this goes into the answer, I will add the tick.